# What might be the cause of following error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class, factory

What might be the cause of following error.

[image]

Comment: A misconfiguration in Eclipse probably. Try to reinstall some plugins or reinstall Eclipse.

Comment: Have you tried to clean the workspace? It should be enough to try Project - Clean and then execute again.